# How to detect specific error type using an error type imported from redux-api-middleware

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux-api-middleware

In my react native app, I'm trying to handle custom errors from a third party library: redux-api-middleware. The documentation indicates the custom error type exports but when I import and then check for type equality it does not work. When I debug the imported error type doesn't seem to have any value even though the [documentation](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#requesterror) indicates this should be an export. Am I importing wrong? Comparing wrong? Or something else?

```
import {RequestError} from 'redux-api-middleware';

const authMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.error) {
    if (action.payload) { // not all actions have payloads
      if (action.payload instanceof RequestError) {
        showNetworkAlert();
      }
    }
  }

  next(action);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import looks correct - [here's](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/blob/master/src/index.js#L48) where `RequestError` is exported. I don't have an easy way to test this, but one guess is that you might need to test `action.error` instead of `action.payload`, i.e. `if (action.error instanceof RequestError) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip--unfortunately error is a boolean that indicates its an error, payload contains the actual error